# The least average number of Corona virus tests

Tags: probability, contest-math, combinatorial-designs

Suppose in a finite population (of size $n$), all configuration of individuals infected with the Corona virus (numbering $2^n$) are equally likely.

Consider the coronavirus testing procedure where there is a finite number of testing rounds. In each round, the population is grouped into not necessarily disjoint subsets. The swabs of all individuals in each subset are collected into one test tube and tested collectively for the presence of infection in that subset in the form of a binary result, i.e. either positive ($+$) or negative ($-$).  There may be a subset not tested. The testing round terminates once all infected individuals are identified.

What is the design of the above rounds and the associated grouping in each round so that on average the total number of tests is the least?

---

I ask for the mean since the least of number of tests for the worst case is always the size of the population.

---

Here are two example procedures. Suppose the population size is $4$. Represent the individuals by the binary numbers $\{00,01,10,11\}$.

1. In round 1, we make $3$ groups. The first consists of the individual $00$ alone. The second group consists of individuals whose first from the left digit is $1$ and the third of those whose second from the left digit is $1$. The swabs of all individuals are put into one test tube and tested once. The infection status of $00$ is at once settled. If group $2$ is $+$ and group $3$ is $-$. We know only $10$ is infected amongst $\{01,10,11\}$. Similarly for the case of group $2$ being $-$ and group $3$ being $+$. If both are $-$, the test is terminated. If both are $+$, we have to relabel the individuals $\{01,10,11\}$ by $\{00,01,10\}$ and proceed to round $2$.

In round 2, we proceed the same way as before. In effect, we test the three individuals one by one.

The whole test procedure then terminates.

2. Another way simple procedure is to build a binary tree partition according to the binary representation. Round 1. Test the whole population. Round 2. Partition the population into two disjoint groups. The first consists of the individuals whose first left digit is $0$ whereas the second of those whose first left digit is $1$. In round 3., further partition each previous group according to whether the second left digit is $0$ or $1$.

Comment: [Group testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_testing)

Comment: Since you asked about viruses, the (expected) optimum procedure depends on the expected proportion of negatives. There is also the problem of stocking and mixing the samples, those are more operations having a cost

Comment: @reuns: You are right about the distribution of infection. I intended to but neglected to add the supposition of uniform distribution. I have edited my question. Please review.

Answer (score 1):

Given the uniform distribution of the results, the optimal procedure is to test each individual individually.

In short, the reason is that to gain maximal information, a test should have probability $\frac12$ to yield either result, and if each individual independently has probability $\frac12$ of being infected, then individual tests are the only ones with this property.

We can get rid of the complication of the rounds, since any test schedule with rounds of tests combined could just as well be executed one test at a time.

More generally, say you want to distinguish between $m$ different outcomes (in your case $m=2^n$), and you can perform tests that tell you whether the outcome is in some arbitrary subset with $k$ of the $m$ outcomes. (This is more powerful than your tests, which only allow for some subsets of the $2^n$ outcomes.) We can prove by strong induction over $m$ that you need at least $\log_2m$ (in your case $n$) tests on average to identify the outcome.

For the base case $m=1$, this is clearly correct: $\log_21=0$, and we need $0$ tests to distinguish $1$ outcome.

Assume that it’s correct for all values less than $m$. If you run a test with a subset for $k$ of the $m$ outcomes, then with probability $\frac km$ you’ll be left with $k$ outcomes to distinguish and with probability $\frac{m-k}m$ you’ll be left with $m-k$ outcomes to distinguish, so by the induction hypothesis the expected number of tests required is at least

$$
1+\frac km\log_2k+\frac{m-k}m\log_2(m-k)=\log_2m+1+\frac km\log_2\frac km+\frac{m-k}m\log_2\frac{m-k}m\;.
$$

The last two terms are the negative binary entropy of the Bernoulli distribution with probability $p=\frac km$, which takes its minimal value $-1$ for $p=\frac12$. It follows that you can’t do better than $\log_2m$, and that this optimal average is achieved only if each test distinguishes exactly half of the remaining outcomes.

On the other hand, if the individuals have an independent probability $p\lt\frac12$ of being infected, then group testing may be beneficial. For instance, for two individuals, if you test them individually you are certain to require $2$ tests, whereas if you first test them as a group, then $A$ if necessary and then $B$ if necessary, you need $1$ test if neither is infected, $2$ tests if $A$ is not infected but $B$ is, and $3$ tests if $A$ is infected, for an average of

$$
(1-p)^2\cdot1+(1-p)p\cdot2+p\cdot3=1+3p-p^2\;,
$$

which is less than $2$ for $p\lt\frac{3-\sqrt5}2\approx38\%$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Before I read further, I would like to seek clarification of one statement of yours "a test should have probability $\frac12$ to yield either result". I do not understand what you exactly mean. My assumption is that for a test performed on a group of individuals, the test gives positive result if and only if at least one of the individuals is infected and gives negative result if and only if none of the individual is infected. Is this assumption compatible with your formulation?

Comment: @Hans: It is. Since the individuals have independent probabilities of $\frac12$ of being infected (that's equivalent to saying that their $2^n$ collective infection states are equiprobable), testing an individual will yield either result with probability $\frac12$, whereas testing any group of more than one individual will be more likely to yield a positive than a negative result, and this asymmetry is wasteful since the test on average gains $p\log_2 p+(1-p)\log_2(1-p)$ bits of information if its results have probabilities $p$ and $1-p$.

Comment: @Hans: (This is of course only true initially; after some tests, the posterior probabilities of subsequent group tests yielding either result may become more symmetrical; but you were quoting from my informal summary of the idea behind the result; the detailed proof takes the changes in probabilities due to previous test results into account.)

Comment: @Hans: Perhaps the source of the confusion lies in the word "should"? I mean it should have this symmetric probability if it is to gain as much information on average as possible.

Comment: I appreciate your explanation. My second question concerns with your statement "If you run a test with a subset  ... $m-k$ outcomes to distinguish" puzzles me slightly. The $1$ comes from the test performed on $k$ of the $m$ outcomes, right? You partition the $m$ outcomes into two disjoint subsets. I see the plausibility of the optimality this assumption but am not sure of its truthfulness. Can you prove it? I question it because of the following example. Suppose there is only $1$ person out of $1024$ is infected. The optimal procedure is to label the people in binary numbers.

Comment: Give $10$ tests the $k$'th of which is performed on the person whose $k$'th digit is $1$. So the subsets of the outcomes upon which the tests are performed overlap each other rather than disjoint as assumed by your answer. What do I miss?

Comment: @Hans: You seem to be confusing overlapping subsets of persons with overlapping subsets of outcomes. You can of course carry out tests on overlapping groups of persons. So in your example you perform a test on the people whose first digit is $1$, and then you perform a test on the people whose second digit is $1$. The result of the first test excludes certain outcomes, so the second test has fewer outcomes left to distinguish. That has nothing to do with the fact that the sets of outcomes in your case are defined via groups of people who can overlap.

Comment: @Hans: In the question, you envisaged multiple tests happening simultaneously in "rounds". But there's no advantage in that over doing them one after the other, so I consider them one after the other because that's a lot easier conceptually. If you view them in this way, each test excludes a certain set of outcomes, and each later test only operates on the remaining possible outcomes that haven't been excluded by previous tests yet. So in each step the set of $2^n$ possible outcomes is reduced, ideally by a factor $2$; then we only need $n$ tests; if the factor is less, we need more tests.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105862/discussion-between-hans-and-joriki).

Comment: Will you be so kind as to come into the chat room to discuss a bit? Thanks, joriki.

Comment: I did try to distinguish the overlapping subsets of persons with overlapping subsets of outcomes. For example, if we have $4$ people and the person labeled $11$ is infected. The outcome $(0,0,0,1)$ (in lexicographic order of the labeling) is covered by both tests in digit $1$ and $2$ counting from the left. What do I miss in this case?

Comment: @Hans: I'm in the chat now (don't know whether you get notified when I write there).